# Do I pay vat on digital goods from EU in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, vat

As a B2C purchase I am wondering if I should be charged for VAT.

The company is from Spain
I am from the UK

I have found it hard to pinpoint an answer for this online.